# Can a navigation Drawer be declared on a Fragment?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I got a navigation drawer on the activity of my app, but once I get the fragment parts of my app running (through a fragmentActivity) I have trouble programming a navigation process over there. I want my users to be able to navigate from one fragment to another fragment  using the navigation drawer, making life easier.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), and to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to page your Fragments.